# In SPI rom, we configure both Normal and Fast Speed, how can we confirm if SPI clock is using fast speed or normal speed?

Tags: spi

In SPI rom, we configure both Normal Speed i.e. 33Mhz and Fast Speed that is 66Mhz.
How can we confirm if SPI clock frequency is fast speed or normal speed?
Does SPI clock frequency changes based on type of spi read commands like 0xB and 0x3?

Do different SPI commands/instruction are based on which spimode (dual/quad) is set ?

SPI quad instruction/commands:
“Fast Read Quad Output(6Bh)”,
“Fast Read Quad I/O (EBh)

SPI dual instruction/commands:
“Fast Read Dual Output (3Bh)”
“Fast Read Dual I/O (BBh)”

Answer (score 0):

The SPI clock is not defined by the SPI memory chip, it is defined by the SPI host. So simply sending different commands would not change any clocks automatically.

Comment: ok, then what is the significant of these two speeds?

Comment: The memory chip can work faster with the other command than with the other command. So if the device that wants to access the memory chip has set clock higher than 33 MHz but below 66 MHz, it must use the fast read command. If the device is using clocks at 33 MHz or below, it does not matter which command is used.

Comment: Do different SPI commands/instruction are based on which spimode (dual/quad) is set ?
e.g.
SPI quad instruction/commands: “Fast Read Quad Output(6Bh)”, “Fast Read Quad I/O (EBh)

SPI dual instruction/commands: “Fast Read Dual Output (3Bh)” “Fast Read Dual I/O (BBh)”

Comment: A datasheet would explain how each command works, and which maximum speeds are available for any command. I don't know which chip you are working on because you have not mentioned it.